# VScode not able to find JAR

Tags: antlr4, visual-studio-code

I have downloaded `antlr4` JAR (`antlr-4.8-complete.jar`) to `/usr/local/lib` and have added it to the `CLASSPATH` as `CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/lib/antlr-4.8-complete.jar"`.

I saved the following grammar as `Hello.g4` in vscode

```
grammar Hello;

welcome: 'hello' ID;
ID: [a-zA-Z]+;
SPACE: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

and got an `antlr4-runtime` folder with a bunch of java files. I can compile those in terminal with `javac *.java`. However `antlr` imports (`import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ParserRuleContext;` and others) are not found in vscode and it does not compile.

I cannot find a way to add the JAR to this project in vscode.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to the .classpath file created in vscode.
`<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/usr/local/lib/antlr-4.8-complete.jar"/>`